# Translating binary data from a file into a very large base-ten integer

Tags: java, algorithm, time-limit-exceeded, integer, serialization

I'm making an experimental Java algorithm that translates binary data from a file into a (very large) base ten integer. I am using `BigInteger` since this number may have millions of digits. I am trying to translate this number into a sum of powers of 2.

I tried this code, which theoretically works, but is sluggishly slow. Using this code for a 200000 digit number takes about 5 minutes to complete with my i5 @4.5GHz. The execution time for a number with over a billion digits could take a day or more.

How could I optimize this code so that the execution time is significantly lowered?

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(outFile.toPath());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
    }
    BigInteger dataInt = new BigInteger(sb.toString(), 16);
    BigInteger remainder = dataInt;
    double dataLength = dataInt.bitCount();
    while (dataLength > BASE.bitCount()) {
        int increment = (int) Math.round(Math.pow(dataLength, 1 / BASE.doubleValue()));
        BigInteger base = BASE;
        int exp = 2;
        while (base.compareTo(remainder) < 0) {
            base = BASE.pow(exp);
            exp += increment;
        }
        while (base.compareTo(remainder) > 0) {
            base = BASE.pow(exp);
            exp--;
        }
        remainder = remainder.subtract(base);
        dataLength = remainder.bitCount();
    }
```

In this case, the constant `BASE` is 2.

Comment: `translates binary data … into a … base ten integer` `translate this number into a sum of powers of 2` What is the goal? And what does `200000 digit number` mean - 7526 bytes? Multi-word base conversion _is_ costly if none of the bases is an integer multiple of the other. Did you try [constructing a BigInteger from a byte array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-byte:A-)? _How_ do you expect `BigInteger` to help?

Comment: What is the `while`-loop supposed to accomplish?

Comment: What exactly are you trying  to accomplish?  Your loop does nothing but waste time since it doesn't generate any output.  What is the output of your program supposed to be?  You claim to want to turn binary data into sums of powers of 2 but that is exactly what binary data is in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(outFile.toPath());
```

Reserving the fully needed space ensures not using extra space, and no reallocations.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
    }
    BigInteger dataInt = new BigInteger(sb.toString(), 16);
```

Then however it would be faster to do:

```
    BigInteger dataInt = new BigInteger(1, bytes);
```

with the caveat, that this is a **big endian** interpretation. Reverting the bytes would be fast too however.

The actual algorithm unfortunately uses floating point, but that is your choice.
You could look at the sources of their implementation of [toString(radix)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString-int-).

Also BigInteger has some interesting methods, like `modPow` or `remainder`.

Whether or not the loops can be optimized, pow multiplied by base, or the loop entirely eliminated. that is something interesting I leave upto you.